Strip signatures from PDFs without increasing the file size, on Linux
I have multiple digitally signed PDF payslips from my ex employer, and I want to merge them together into one. I don't care about the signatures: either retaining them or signing the merged document.
I'm using KDE Neon, with the default document viewer Okular and PDFChain (GUI for pdftk) to merge them. PDFChain wont merge signed documents.
One way forward is to print each file to PDF and then merge the resulting unsigned PDFs, but the printed PDF from Okular is huge (10KB -> over 500 KB, multiplied by around 20 files in all).
So is there a way to either:

Print to pdf more efficiently, without the bloat in file size (Okular's PDF print settings aren't making any changes to the source that I can see, i.e. same formatting and margins as the original)
strip the signatures using any other tool?

I'm looking for any suggestions - be it tweaks to Okular's printing, or a separate tool altogether. Should also add I'm using KDE Plasma 6.

Ended up using PDFSam Basic, which I found through Neon's Discover software manager.
Props to K J's answer below as well.

Single signed Payslips

Payslips merged with GhostScript (the links are retained as are the signers visuals) and the finished file is smaller than all the parts.
GS -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o Payslips-2024.pdf -f PS001-2024-01.pdf PS001-2024-02.pdf PS001-2024-03.pdf etc.
To avoid listing all the filenames on the command line you can easily add them in Linux using *.pdf or in a listing @filelist.txt
GS -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o Payslips-2024.pdf -f @filelist.txt

